# VBA - Finding & Changing values across sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Good evening! Been searching all over, and I'm afraid I've just got something completely backwards (I don't know too much about Excel/VBA and and 99% sure I'm doing everything that most difficult way possible).
What I'm trying to do is find a value from another sheet, and change it.

```
For i = SORowStart To SORowEnd
'Grabbing this information PID and QTY from my main sheet. 

ProductID = Range("B" & i).Value
ProductQty = Range("A" & i).Value

'I then need to match up PID on another sheet, and modify its Qty
If (Len(ProductID) > 0) Then
    'Finding old quantity, successfully..but how do I change it?? 
    OldQty = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, Worksheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable"), 4, False)
    'MsgBox (ProductID & " - SELLING:" & ProductQty & "/" & OldQty)


    'SO HERES MY PROBLEM LINE! ****************************
    'I've tried with and without the "Set" keyword too. 
    'Set Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, Worksheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable"), 4, False).Value = (OldQty - ProductQty)


End If
```

Next i

If anyone could point me in the right direction or tell me what keywords to search for, anything would be incredibly helpful...I've been stumped on this for hours now -*_*-
I've tried to find the address of the OldQty cell, but no success. It seems possible to do within the Excel Cell Formulas (using =ADDRESS and =MATCH (?)) but I haven't a clue doing it inside VBA. Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seen that the VLOOKUP function is returning a value not a range reference. I will give you an example using MATCH and INDEX function:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ProductIDs As Range
    Dim OldQty As Range

    Set ProductIDs = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable"), 0, 1)

    For i = 1 To 2
        'Grabbing this information PID and QTY from my main sheet.

        ProductID = Range("B" & i).Value
        ProductQty = Range("A" & i).Value

        'I then need to match up PID on another sheet, and modify its Qty
        If (Len(ProductID) > 0) Then
            'Finding old quantity, successfully..but how do I change it??
            'MsgBox ProductID
            RowIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ProductID, ProductIDs, 0)

            Set OldQty = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ProductIDs, RowIndex, 1).Offset(0, 3)
            'OldQty = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, Sheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable"), 4, False)
            MsgBox (ProductID & " - SELLING:" & ProductQty & "/" & OldQty)


            'SO HERES MY PROBLEM LINE! ****************************
            'I've tried with and without the "Set" keyword too.
            'Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, Worksheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable"), 4, False) = (OldQty - ProductQty)
            OldQty = (OldQty - ProductQty)


        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Check this page http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php

Comment: Excellent! Thank you both for the reply, I was able to figure it out using Match and Index functions! However, I then destroyed all my work trying to use copy/save/print/close functions -_- back to the blank worksheet drawing board, sigh..haha.

Comment: I'll update my post to include my final solution ... once I recreate it

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you save before doing so, but try this:

```
Sub findstuff()

    Dim currQuantityCell As Range, _
        found As Range, _
        invSheetPIDCol As Range, _
        currQuantityRng As Range, _
        invQuantityRng As Range

    'The range containing your quantities
    Set currQuantityRng = Range("A1:A6")

    'Your PID col inside your range "List_InventoryTable"
    Const PIDCol As Long = 1

    'Your old quantity column inside your range "List_InventoryTable"
    Const oldQuantCol As Long = 4

    Set invSheetPIDCol = Sheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable").Columns(PIDCol)

    For Each currQuantityCell In currQuantityRng
        If currQuantityCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Set found = invSheetPIDCol.find(currQuantityCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, lookat:=xlwhole)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                Set invQuantityRng = found.Offset(0, oldQuantCol - PIDCol)
                invQuantityRng.Value = invQuantityRng.Value - currQuantityCell.Value
            Else
                MsgBox "Could not find PID for row " & currQuantityCell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next currQuantityCell

End Sub
```

If you're not sure about any part of this, ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Here is my final result:

```
Dim SORowStart As Integer       ' Sales Order - Starting row of line items
Dim SORowEnd As Integer         ' Sales Order - Ending row of line items
SORowStart = Range("OrderRowStart").Value
SORowEnd = Range("OrderRowEnd").Value

Dim ItemToSell As String        ' Sales Order - Selected item PID
Dim QtyToSell As Integer        ' Sales Order - Quantity of item to sell

Dim MatchedIDRow As Integer     ' Inventory sheet - Line # the PID is located on'
Dim Range_InventoryIDs As Range ' Inventory sheet - Range of selectable product IDs
Dim InventoryQty As Range       ' Inventory sheet - Range of selected products Qty

Set Range_InventoryIDs = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("List_InventoryTable"), 0, 1)



For i = SORowStart To SORowEnd

    ItemToSell = Range("B" & i).Value
    QtyToSell = Range("A" & i).Value

    If (Len(ItemToSell) > 0) Then
        MatchedIDRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ItemToSell, Range_InventoryIDs, 0)
        Set InventoryQty = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range_InventoryIDs, MatchedIDRow, 1).Offset(0, 3)

        MsgBox ("Selling " & ItemToSell & " - " & QtyToSell & " / " & InventoryQty.Value)
        InventoryQty.Value = InventoryQty.Value - QtyToSell

        MsgBox ("Remaining " & ItemToSell & " = " & InventoryQty.Value)
    End If
Next i
```